# Pandas dataset differences member-wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, difference

I'm looking for a solution to this problem:
I have two set of datas, same dimention and same formatting, both coming from the same software.
I want to plot the differences between these two datasets.

I tried subtracting the datasets in every possible ways but the result is always the following: when I subtract from one 43x64 panda dataset another 43x64 dataset i obtain a 43x127 datasets of NaN with some strange values in the header.

```
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    0.020408  0.020516  0.020574  ...  0.998493  0.998988  1.000000
0        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       0.0
1        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       0.0
2        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       0.0
...
41       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       0.0
42       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       0.0
```

How can i obtain a 43x64 dataset with differences in it?

Comment: please put df.head() and df1.head() data here so we can see the data, (df and df1 being the two dataframes you have). We cannot guess whats in the data...

Comment: I have no header in the file, might this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` to be the two dataframes with same index and column names.

try this:

```
df1=df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2=df2.reset_index(drop=True)

df2.columns = [str(col) + '_n' for col in df2.columns]


final1=df2.merge(df1,left_index=True,right_index=True)


final1=final1.reindex(sorted(final1.columns), axis=1)


final2=pd.DataFrame()
for col in df1.columns:
    final2['{}_diff'.format(col)]=final1[col].fillna(0)-final1['{}_n'.format(col)].fillna(0)

final2=final2.filter(like='_diff',axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried to your solution but it gave some issues with keys. Might it be linked to the fact that i don't have any header in the dataset and it takes the first row as header?

Comment: The issue was the absence of headers in the dataset: I added an header and the simple subtraction is now woking.

Thank you all for the help ;)